# QImage resizing

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, sprite

I'm coding small graphics editor and need some help.
I'm painting QImage like this:

```
void Editor::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // zoom is an int, representing zoomFactor from 1 to 12.
    painter.drawImage(
        QRect(0, 0, image.width() * zoom , image.height() * zoom),
        image);

    if (zoom >= 3 && showGrid) {
        painter.setPen(palette().foreground().color());
        painter.setPen(Qt::DotLine);

        // this is how I draw grid
        for (int i = 0; i <= image.width(); ++i)
            painter.drawLine(zoom * i, 0,
                zoom * i, zoom * image.height());
        for (int j = 0; j <= image.height(); ++j)
            painter.drawLine(0, zoom * j,
                zoom * image.width(), zoom * j); 
    }

    // (...)
}
```

It works fine with images like this (16 x 16)
[image: 1]

Troubles begin when I open images like this (25 X 28)

[image: 2]

As you can see pixels are drawn with different width and height!
What am I doing wrong? Please, help :)

**UPD:** Problem solved unexpectedly. I noticed, that Editor was QGLWidget, so I tried to change it to QWidget and everything worked just fine. Stupid me -_-
Btw, may be there's more convenient ways to zoom image?(like crop pixels, that are not needed to be painted)

Comment: I'm curious -- if your larger image were 25x25 (or 28x28) would the problem still exist? If not, I would suspect that the rendering is scaling the image to fit its layout, the layout size is of a non-square ratio, and the scaling of width is independent from that of height.

Comment: Strange... It works fine only when size is 16x16, 32x32 etc.

Comment: Looks like rounding error in image scaling. What platform is this?

Comment: Could not reproduce, works fine for me, Ubuntu 11.10 KDE

Comment: @winch Please add your solution as an answer to the question, and accept it...as opposed to as an update to the question itself.  It is perfectly acceptable (and encouraged) on SO to answer your own question, if you figure out what the answer is.

Comment: You didn't solve the problem, you found a workaround that apparently works for no logical reason. Are you sure your code is going to work correctly on different systems or with different graphic cards? We have a similar (but not identical) related problem and on my systems IIRC the bug appears using `QWidget` but it's ok when using `QGLWidget`.

Comment: @6502 Unfortunately I can't find logical reason for this. The only thing I changed is defenition of Editor class. I guess that's bug in Qt, not in the code

Answer (score 0):

The code for handling highly zoomed images has been "optimized" some time ago in Qt and now it is unfortunately buggy. I didn't check the code but my wild guess is that texture "speed" or "offset" used for drawing was before computed in floating point and it's now computed using fixed point.

I don't remember exactly with which version this was introduced, but it was quite early after 4.0. We have one of our applications that needs to allow to place a cross with sub-pixel precision and scaling over the point when zoom factor is high you can notice the picture is "wobbling".

I'm the first that would not claim a bug in somone else's code unless 100% sure, but this is one of those cases in which I am indeed 100% sure.

The only way out is to draw the zoomed image manually, either reimplementing texture mapping code or (if you only need `int > 1` zoom factors) by drawing one pixel at a time with `drawRect`... it should be fast enough on a PC.

Note that the bug may be a common bug of video drivers instead of a bug in Qt... I've seen that the problem on our software is present on different platforms (Windows/Linux/OsX) and indeed IIRC only when using `QWidget` (and not when using `QGLWidget`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I tried to draw the image pixel by pixel, it works fine too, but it uses a lot of CPU(25-99%) when I try to paint something on it, using image.setPixel function. This problem doesn't happen, when I use drawImage function to paint the image.